# File not found on import when the same script is imported onto two other python scripts

Tags: python, python-import, importerror

I know this might sound simple but I have been wracking my brain for a while now with no resolution.

I have a python script structured as follows:

```
app
 └── my_resource.py
 └── utils
       └── my_file.py
       └── exceptions
                 └──my_exception.py
```

Both **my_resource.py** and **my_file.py** need to import **my_exception.py**.

As per the structure, I am importing as shown below:

***my_resource.py :***

```py
from utils import my_file as my_file
from utils.exceptions import my_exception as my_exception
```

***my_file.py :***

```py
from exceptions import my_exception as my_exception
```

As per my understanding, as I am *not importing from a different folder*, the import must work. But, I get the following error every time I run my_resource.py.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "my_resource.py", line 9, in <module>
    from utils import my_file as my_file
  File "my_file.py", line 6, in <module>
    from exceptions import my_exception as my_exception
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'exceptions'
```

But, when I remove `from exceptions import my_exception as my_exception`  from **`my_file.py`** module, **my_resource.py** runs successfully.

Why is this the case? Is this because there is some form of nested import here [even then why should there be an import error]?